# UIScrollView: false scroll position

Tags: objective-c, uiscrollview

I change the content of an UIView by clicking of some UIButtons.
(Buttons and UIView are included in the same UIScrollView)

For Example:

Case 1: I add content and raise the height of the View and the ScrollView.

Case 2: I remove content and reduce the height of the View and the ScrollView.

At both cases i set the scroll position:

```
[newsScrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0,240) animated:YES];
```

At Case 1 it worked fine and the ScrollView shows the right content, but at case 2 it scroll at the bottom of the ScrollView.

Does someone knows where 's the mistake?

Comment: in case2 to set [newsScrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0,0) animated:YES];

Comment: In both cases the scroll hight should be 240. the idea is that the first 240 shows the header informations and after this there are navigation buttons for more informations. after the clicking i change the content of an view and the first position of the scroll view is the navigation (and the header informations are on top of this in the hidden area of the scroll view)

Answer (score 0):

Your scrollview is doing exactly what you are telling it to do.  You need to make sure you are setting your UIScrollView's `contentSize` properly to reflect the amount of content you have within it, which may be different if you are removing and adding content.

If you are setting your offset to (0, 240), and it is scrolling to the bottom, it's likely because your `contentSize` is shorter than 240.

Comment: If i change the content, i change the content size of the scroll view too. 

The size of the scroll view is in each case higher then 240, because the high of the scrollview is structured like this: 240 header informations + 40 navi + XXX changing content

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the error is based on the iOS versions.

It works fine for:

- Simulator 6.0
- iPhone 4 gs with iOS 6.0.1

and fails for:

- Simulator 5.1
- Simulator 5.0
- iPhone 3 width 5.1.1